# how do I search a project in solution explorer?

Tags: visual-studio

There are more than 600 projects in dozens of folders in my Solution Explorer, not easy to find a project by scrolling in the window.

How do I search or quickly locate a project by name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well my way to find a project now, is to open my project folder and look for `*.vcxproj` files, which have the same project name and in same hierarchy as Solution Explorer.

By this I will know if a project is there, and which folder it will be in the Solution Explorer of VC.

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio 2019, there is a search field in the [Solution Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/use-solution-explorer?view=vs-2019) view:

[image]

That feature wasn't there when you asked the question in 2012.

Answer (score 1):

In your search bar, type ">of " without the quotes and then whatever you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You should start the command window (located on view - other windows - command window), then type the word: `of` and then type your project name and file name, you could only type partial names, it'll autocomplete for you.

For example, after openning the command window start typing:

`of yourprojectname\web.config`

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Solution Explorer.
2. To the right of the Search keyword entry box there is a magnifying glass icon (or if you've already searched then it becomes an X icon).
3. To the right of the magnifying glass icon there is a small drop-down triangle. Click this triangle to open the Search Options.
4. Turn off all the search options by unchecking them.
5. Now when you search by your project name, the number of results returned will be **greatly** reduced, making it simple to spot the project itself.
6. After selecting the project, you may clear the search term and it will remain selected.